# Very simple authentication using Session in asp.net MVC - is this secure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

ASP.NET Identity is extremely complex and overkill for what I need in an ASP.NET MVC 5 app. Keeping things simple is a good principle IMHO.

When a user logs in I simply use Dapper to lookup email & password in the database (hashing & salting used).

Then I set a session["userID"] = user.Id  // from database.

This Id is a high entropy randomly generated string (ie a security stamp that could be revoked - not the actual user ID), and the session timeout is set to a long time - eg 1 month - so users don't have to keep logging in.

Where a user is an administrator I also just set Session["admin"] = true;

I then create a simple class that inherits from AuthorizeAttribute:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.Session["userID"] == null)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Account/Login");
    }
}
```

so I can use authorization attributes on my controllers:

```
[MyAuthorize]
public ActionResult MyController()
{
...
}
```

Is this secure? Are there any steps I am missing to secure this - if so what?

Is something so wrong with this it will fail in operation?

Is session capable of doing this? If not what is & what would be a better way (that is just as simple)?

Comment: this is exactly why you should not even attempt to write your own thing. If your website will end up in the wild and used by people then don't take chances with their data. 

The Identity might seem overkill but it works and is secure. It's already been proven in the wild. Your stuff is not.

Comment: I would argue that something so complicated is likely to have a lot of problems in the wild (if not inherently, in people's implementation of it) - especially when MS continually change how it works. If there is one thing that is insecure it's complexity. Can you address any specific problems in the above?

Comment: @niico do you have any references saying Identity is not secure?

Comment: @trailmax My issue isn't Identity not being secure, it is that Identity is WAY too complicated introducing layers of abstraction - which could lead to many issues. I want something very simple - like the above.

Comment: @niico in that case I'd abstain from making such a big claims about insecurity and complexity.

Comment: @niico - if your perception is that Identity is "too complicated", then perhaps you should look into building your own security *extension* using the `IPrincipal` \ `IIdentity` interfaces. But, this is not what session state is for - see [Think twice about using session state](https://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/). But if you have no idea what *is* secure and what is *not* secure, then I suggest you learn and use Identity - at least there is a chance that others will be able to understand it if you do (meaning you don't have to write so much documentation).

Comment: @trailmax Complexity is the enemy of security - this is not a controversial statement IMHO. If you have any comments on the OP please go ahead and make them.

Comment: @NightOwl888 I take your point on other being able to edit the code later - I am still considering Identity for this reason. What about using a cookie instead of session for the ID? (I was never planning to store more than an ID in session).

Comment: @niico - I suggest you look through some of the articles on Brock Allen's blog (the link above). He shows some good approaches for securing cookies. He also has some open source alternatives to [Membership](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot) and [Identity](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.IdentityReboot). But his advice is the same as mine - if you have to ask "is this secure?", you probably shouldn't be making a custom authentication system. Leave that to those who know the most current vulnerabilities and how to patch them - you get that for free with Identity

Comment: Identity is not "insecure", and it's *certainly* more secure than anything you'd create on your own. Identity is in production use by millions of developers and is thoroughly tested. Your code will not be. It's also not "complex". It's actually pretty basic, honestly.

Comment: Also, you might want to learn a little bit more about OOP. Abstraction actually *simplifies* code. Abstraction solves problems, it doesn't introduce them.

Comment: I strongly disagree with your claim that asp.net identity is too complex and I believe you claim this because you have not taken the time to understand it yet. Visual Studio's Mvc templates make use of it and show how easy it is to introduce and consume. I recommend you take a little time to read through a tutorial and the template code to see how it works. It will be worth it. Also you will spend much less time doing this (and using Identity) compared to time spent with your idea of a secure session authentication because you will spend more time there with patching and securing and testing.

Comment: Most importantly session state is not secure and was not designed to be secure. Asp.net Identity, on the other hand, is secure and is designed to be secure by developers who are concerned with security. If you want your application to be secure then do not try to do it yourself unless you just do not care about the outcome/result.

Comment: OK you persuaded me thanks. Feel free to leave an answer below that I'll accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I don't agree with your comments about complexity. So far ASP.Net Identity is the most comprehensive and well-composed authentication/authorisation framework for .Net. It is superior to all predecessors with a lot of possible extensibility points. If you think this is very complex, then think of a security in general - it is a very complex domain with high risks involved. Identity framework actually simplifies and hides a lot of complexity so you don't have to deal with this. If you still insist this is complex... well, yes, software development is a complex business. Computing in general is complex... well, life is complex!

Anyway, back to your solution. I can see **at least one** major flaw with your solution. You keep your users authenticated by session cookie. You propose the session to be a very long lived. This means that session cookie is not changed for a long time. So in case somebody have managed to gain access to the session somehow, they will have a very long window of opportunity to abuse the access to your system as somebody else. 
Identity solves this problem by rotating the cookie - by default every 30 minutes the auth cookie value is changed. So if you get somebody's yesterday cookie value - it won't be any good. You can also reduce this value to couple minutes or even make the cookie value update on every request.

Then you'll need to think about session expiry and management. First this will be a memory hog - for every user logged in the last 30 days you'll have to maintain a live session on your server. Imagine a thousand users logged on... I don't know how much data you'll have per user session, but given enough use you'll start hitting memory problems. Then if you would want to load-balance your servers, you'll have to introduce a sticky session. Also when your server restarts, all your users will loose their sessions (I've used this kind of system - it is horrid).

Next thing you'll have to take care of multiple user logins - what will happen when the same user logs in from 2 different browsers? What happens to user sessions when user changes password - how does it log out other browsers?

I've not done a terrible amount of work with session, so I'm not sure how session cookie is created. But looking on [documentation (Session Identifiers section)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx#Background) sessionId is stored in the cookie. And you propose to put User.Id into that session cookie. **That means that if `User.Id` is known to an attacker, then they can log in as that user any time they like.** To mitigate that you'll have to come up with the way to hide user id inside the session and use some sort of correlation id, and even then you are not escaping the fact that once created correlation id will last entire session life - 30 days. Talking about complex solution?

Identity provides you a lot of functionality out of the box. Things that you probably won't need now but might in the future. And with home-grown solution this will be a case of writing this yourself.

- Validate newly registered emails
- 2-Factor Authentication
- Social logins
- Password strength requirements
- Username/email uniqueness requirement
- User Lockout
- Mitigate password sharing
- Password reset through email link

List is not exhaustive - just something from top of my head.

Comment: I agree Identity is a big improvement over what came before - and is very extensible. I don't use user ID in session - but instead use a security stamp. If we want to logout a user (ie revoke a login) we can just change that stamp - or just routinely change it - then the ID in the session is no longer valid. What about using a cookie instead of session? I don't like much of the way Identity does lots of the things in your list - I prefer dataAnnotations to validate my models for example.

Comment: @niico you can still use data annotations - these are view models anyway, they can be replaced.

Comment: @niico I'm not sure I understand the purpose of your question - you ask "how secure this is", then you get a lot of people who know what they are talking about (Chris Pratt,  NightOwl888) saying don't do this, linking to well known and reviewed articles by Brock Allen. Yet you still insist building your own security. If you are so convinced, just do it and don't ask.